# Problems reading IBM 3592 JB tape

Tags: linux, tape

I'm having problems reading a 3592 JB IBM (700GB) tape using a TS1140 (E07) drive. The tape was written using a TS1130 (E06) drive with compression up to 1TB as specified on the label of the tape. According to IBM's tape specifications webpage, the TS1140 drives should be backward compatible to read tapes written in TS1120 (E05) and TS1130 drives. However, when I attempt to read this tape it throws an I/O error and stalls at around 240mb. I have managed to get up to 8GB from the tape using `dd` with a block size of 256K, however this stalls as well.

Eg.

```
[user1@server-le1 ~]$ dd if=/dev/IBMtape10 of=/myoutputpath/File_1.dat bs=512k
dd: reading `/dev/IBMtape10': Input/output error
0+46011 records in
0+46011 records out
379301796 bytes (379 MB) copied, 833.756 s, 455 kB/s
```

Is anyone experienced with IBM tape drives able to help me resolve this issue?

The tape creator has said they are able to read this using their 1140 drives. So I'm thinking is this a drive setting that needs to be changed? Or is there something else?

Comment: https://community.emc.com/thread/202091?start=0&tstart=0 seems to suggest the block size should be 384KiB. Curious to know whether that works better then your 256KiB block size. ([Another reference](http://www-01.ibm.com/common/ssi/cgi-bin/ssialias?subtype=ca&infotype=an&supplier=897&letternum=ENUS108-494) suggests 32KiB but I'm not sure whether it's quoting a comparable performance indicator or it's referring to the default block size.)

Comment: @roaima thanks for the suggestions, I have had a look at your second reference and had no success. I am currently trying `bs=384K` and so far it seems to have retrieved over 2GB. I will let you know if it finishes.

Comment: @roaima unfortunately this didnt work either. It only managed to copy 5.4GB. I am starting to think that I need to look at updating tape drivers perhaps and also looking at other options for copying the data over. I am not too sure if this is a block size issue, but a tape drive setting maybe.

Comment: Wondering if the data has Logical EOF markers in it. To handle these you need the non-rewind-on-close device and you loop reading the next section from the tape until you hit EOT.

Comment: The data does have single EOF makers and double to determine EOT. There should be 5 EOF file markers on this particular tape. And I do have a Perl written script to handle these using `dd`, however it still does not read the entire tape. The most I could get was using `conv=noerror,sync` flag using `dd`. I got 137GB then it failed with I/O error again.

Comment: What is the I/O error? Is an error code provided? How about the syslog?

Answer (score 3):

Throwing a couple of ideas here.  This might solve your issue or not at all, but I'd try to copy the contents using `cat`:

```
cat /dev/IBMtape10 > /myoutputpath/File_1.dat
```

This because `cat` will automatically adjust the blocksize to an optimum value according to the available I/O speed, without forcing a specified buffer size.

You might try also to operate directly on `/dev/IBMtape10` via the `mt` command.

Comment: Great, I will try the `cat` cmd tomorrow when I have access to the server. However, can you elaborate on the `mt` command? Can it be used to output data to a file? I have tried doing a `status` using `mt` and also `fsf 1` to go to the first file mark, however I receive I/O errors.

Comment: I think you use `mt` to position the tape head, then `dd` or `cat` to write to an external file.  I don't use tape drives often :/ but the manpage has some useful information on it.  Here's some other info: https://www.cyberciti.biz/hardware/unix-linux-basic-tape-management-commands/

Comment: Unfortunately, `cat` failed also. And yes, I have tried using `mt` to position to the first EOF marker, but this returns an I/O error as well. At this stage we have contacted IBM to confirm our tape drivers are up to date and seek further support from them. Thanks for your suggestions.